# Fitting distributions using the dispersion of Z-scores

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, fitting, z-score

I work for a medical testing company and I've inherited some legacy code written by someone who has since left. I understand the reasoning behind most of what is there, but the final step is something which, while effective, I don't understand the justification for (or what the procedure would be called).

At this point in the model it's constructed a background distribution for our test statistic (basically enrichment), but this needs to fitted to the actual data which frequently has a different mean. The way this mean is fitted is by minimising the the mean absolute deviation of the z-scores for a given mean. The code is reasonably straightforward (once you understand all the nested closures...) and passes the distrubition function to R's built-in `optim()`.

What I am curious about is:

1. Is this a common approach to model fitting, and, if so, does it have a name?
2. What assumptions are needed for this approach to be valid?

NB Of course empirical validation is carried out no there is no question of whether this *works*, but I'm still curious to see if modification should make it better.